# What's a good way to level pottery?

Tags: everquest

I'm working on [Coldain Prayer Shawl 1.0 #4: Fur-lined Coldain Prayer Shawl](http://www.eqtraders.com/articles/article_page.php?article=q133), and want to get my pottery skill over 122? What's the fastest way to do this?

Comment: http://www.eqtraders.com/items/show_item.php?item=3941 with  Crows Special Brew.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1

You will need (at most) 50pp to purchase the following ingredients:

- Medium Jar Sketch x 80
- Medium Bowl Sketch x 300+
- [Block of Clay](http://www.eqtraders.com/items/show_item.php?item=1300) x 400+
- Water Flask x 400+

There are many merchants around the world. As a druid i found it best to use South Ro merchants for the Sketches, and Kelethin for the Pottery Wheel and Water/Clay.
The Pottery Wheel is located in the SE corner of Kelethin (at -204, -540 +161) and the Clay merchant Merchant Legweien is (at +410, +371, +78) platform north of POD lift.

Step 2

Make [Unfired Medium Container](http://www.eqtraders.com/items/show_item.php?item=3936&menustr=035000000000) until you hit skill 36

When you do successfully combine into Unfired Medium Container, just drop it on the ground. Merchants will not take it unless you use a Firing Sheet with it. Which is way too time consuming to matter, since Firing Sheets do not stack either. So you will find yourself running back and forth way too much, and it is not worth it. Its better to eat the money.

Step 3

Make [Unfired Medium Bowl](http://www.eqtraders.com/items/show_item.php?item=4437&menustr=035000000000) until you hit skill 122

When you do successfully combine into Unfired Medium Bowl, just drop it on the ground. Merchants will not take it unless you use a Firing Sheet with it. Which is way too time consuming to matter, since Firing Sheets do not stack either. So you will find yourself running back and forth way too much, and it is not worth it. Its better to eat the money.

Source: http://wiki.project1999.com/Skill_Pottery

Comment: better to get to 54 in crescent reach for free(skip step 2 above).